# In my test, how do I assert if a value is greater than zero?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, assert, minitest

With Rails 5.1, PostGres 9.4 and minitest.  I have this column in my PostGres table

```
 total_paid         | double precision            |
```

And I have this in my test/fixtures/workers.yml file

```
one:
  username: MyString
  password: MyString
  enabled: true
  total_paid: 0.00001
```

But in my test, although I can see the value is set through my "puts" statement, the last assertion is failing

```
  test "Test total paid" do
    worker = workers(:one)
    puts "#{worker.inspect}"
    assert_operator worker.total_paid, :>, 0, "A pre-condition of this test is that the stratum worker's total paid must be greater than zero."
```

It fails with

```
    Failure:
WorkerTest#test_Test_total_paid [/Users/satishp/Documents/workspace/cmine/test/models/worker_test.rb:14]:
Failed to return a non-zero value for total paid..
Expected NaN to be > 0.
```

Comment: What data type is the workers total_paid attribute? can you add your db/schema.rb?

Comment: The precision may be giving you the problem.

Comment: @SebastianPalma, Per my first line, the data type of the PostGres column is "double precision".

Comment: That's the Postgres "representation", but Rails handles data types for model attributes in a different way. I'm asking about that, to try replicating your error.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood.  In my db/schema.rb file the column is defined as "t.float "total_paid".  Is taht what you were asking?

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. Can you add your whole error?

Comment: What do you get for the `worker.inspect`? specifically, what do you get if you do: `worker.paid_total.inspect` (Unrelated note: it is unnecessary to put this inside of a string interpolation eg you do not need `puts "#{worker.inspect}"`, just use `puts worker.inspect` -> `to_s` will automatically be called on any single object you pass to `puts`.)

Comment: try assert worker.total_paid >= 0